# Call 2nd XIB and Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xib

I am teaching myself Obj-C slowly,  I have a project with 2 Classes and each class has a XIB that goes with it.

For ease of testing, they are named One and Two

I changed the plist to make the app start on Two rather than One and that works.

So I am sure (I hope) that both classes and XIBs are OK.

So from One I want to call (view open or whatever its called in ObjC) the Two class and the XIB that goes with it. And then I want to be able to go back to One.  Should be simple eh? I have messed with this for 2 days and still havent got it working.

Does anyone have a sample code that shows how to do this?  I have found several docs on this but I guess I am being slow as I cannot figure it out.

thank you for any help!

---

More Info:  EDIT: bm is the 2nd XIB

```
    bm *screen = [[[bm alloc] initWithNibName:@"bm" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

I added the above code and then got this error on this line

2011-05-09 14:48:23.242 HW[7265:207] *** -[bm initWithNibName:bundle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x392e820
2011-05-09 14:48:23.244 HW[7265:207]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[bm initWithNibName:bundle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x392e820'

Comment: Would putting both into a UINavigationController work for you?

Comment: I really dont know what is best as I am still getting my feet wet.  The first XIB has buttons to go to 6 different sub menus, and these sub menus each could have several more. I think that means I am supposed to make a XIB for each of these menus...

Comment: Most often we use XIBs for UIViewControllers, is bm a UIViewController?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this and it all depends on what you want it to look like.

Present the second view as a modal view controller:

```
ViewControllerName *viewController = [[[ViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Or you can actually swap the view out of the `UIWindow`:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
ViewControllerName *viewController = [[[ViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil] autorelease];
window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Comment: thank you for the details but I think I tried something like this already and it doesnt work. I know I have something wrong but not sure what?  See the extra info I posted above.

Comment: That's strange, your code looks fine. What is bm a subclass of? `UIViewController`?

Comment: Shoot I just made it a class, not a sub class.  I made both of the classes and the XIB and then tested both as the root to see if they worked ok.  I guess that is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, it should be a subclass of `UIViewController` if you want it to manage an `UIView`. Xcode will create this for you, just go to File > New File > Cocoa Touch > UIViewController subclass.

Comment: OK thanks again! I sure appreciate the help!! I created a new class and let it create the XIB at the same time.  I added a label to the view on the new class.  Still get the same error ;(

Comment: untitled *viewController = [[[untitled alloc] initWithNibName:@"untitled" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: 2011-05-09 15:55:35.647 HW[7886:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[HWAppDelegate presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0f650'

Comment: Ahh ok. I see the problem. I didn't know you were doing this in your app delegate. You need to replace `self` with the instance variable of the main `UIViewController`. Not the one you are trying to display, but the one that is already displayed.

Comment: You are AWESOME!  THANK YOU for all the time you have spent with me!  I really appreciate it!!!  You don't do tutoring do you?  Ha! Would have saved me tons of time...

Comment: Not a another dumb question... how do I make it go back to the root?

Comment: To dismiss it do `[viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` where viewController is a variable pointing to the root view controller.

Comment: I have about 70+ classes and 40 views in my Android app. On the iphone Should I have one Navcontroller and all the views under that or what do you think? I originally had thought of making multiple XIBs with a Navcontroller and views on each XIB but some people on this forum think I should do it all in on Navcontroller.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I think it's just a matter of preference. I usually do one class for every view, but I don't have any apps with quite that many views. But it's really up to you.